# Find Current Model is being called

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im trying to sort alphabeticly the name (filter block) on the swatches on the catalog page  (manufacturer, etc..).

I went to the phtml file called "swatches.phtml" and i found that it calls the collection "$this->getItems()", but before calling thie method getItems i need to set the Order, i tryied for example before calling "getItems" this code above:

```
$items=$this->setOrder('updated_at', 'asc');
```

Then call the $items->getItems()" but it doesnt work, anybody have a ideia what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `getItems()` function is being called from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php` and if you look there, you will see that it returns an array of filter-item objects.  You can use a [usort() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort them right in your swatches.phtml.  It will look very similar to the first example in the php manual page:

```
<?php 
function sortByLabel($a, $b) {
    if ($a->getLabel() == $b->getLabel()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->getLabel() < $b->getLabel()) ? -1 : 1;
}

$items = $this->getItems();

usort($items, "sortByLabel");
?>
<!-- you will have to change the existing foreach loop to use your $items array -->
    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
....
```